# How can I check what is the type of the boxed value?

Tags: c#

I box value types:

```
Object boxed = new Object();
boxed = "bla bla bla"; // boxing string
boxed = 10; //boxing int
```

At some point I need to unbox but before value is unboxed I need to check the type before it was boxed?

How can I check what is the type that boxed?

Comment: `GetType()` and `typeof`? - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `if(boxed is FooType) ((FooType)boxed).SomeMethod()`

Comment: `.GetType()` works whether something is boxed or not. But you're using the wrong term to begin with -- you don't care if it's *boxed*, you want to know the type of an object that you've stored as a generic `Object`. Notably, you don't box strings, since they're reference types.

Comment: There are too many obvious answers to this question.  What we can't tell is *why* you need to know, the snippet is particularly unhelpful.  So you can't get the right answer.

Comment: using `is` operator is the simplest way

Comment: @HansPassant is correct. The correct answer depends on what you are doing. What is the context?

Comment: Strings cannot be boxed.  They're reference types already.

Comment: "boxed = "bla bla bla"; // boxing string" there´s no boxing on string or any other reference-type. Boxing only occurs on value-types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call `GetType()` or `is`:

```
if (boxed is int i)
{
    // use i
}
```

Or pre-C# 7:

```
if (boxed is int)
{
    int i = (int)boxed;
    // use i
}
```

String is a reference type already, so no boxing. `int` can be boxed, but still the underlying type returned is the unboxed type.

Comment: The code example used in your answer is C#7, while it may be correct, there was no such version specified and it is not the mainstream version of the C# language, this answer may be confusing for some newbies. I would recommend adding such information.

Comment: Oh, yes. The user knows what boxing is, so not a newbie exactly. Will update.